# Editing outlook contacts using C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I am developing a desktop application using C#, and I do not know how to edit a contact info in outlook, I Google-d it but no use.

I know how to retrieve and add contacts to outlook, what I am asking about is updating contacts.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is quite easy, though I did not find it using google.

1. retrieve the outlook contact.

   ```
       Outlook.Items ctcItems = cf.Items;
       Outlook.Items items = ctcItems;
       Outlook.ContactItem ctc = (Outlook.ContactItem)items[index];
   ```

cf in the code above is the `Outlook.MAPIFolder`.

2. update the `Outlook.ContactItem` .

   ```
   ctc.FullName = "Laurel";
   ```

   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
3. save `Outlook.ContactItem` .

   ```
   ctc.Save();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), then add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` to your project. This will give you access to the Outlook object model.

Comment: ok, I can retrieve and add contacts from outlook, but I cannot update.

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution.**

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

MAPIFolder Folder_Contacts = (MAPIFolder)
outlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);       

var filter = String.Format("[FullName] = '{0}'", "Jose da Silva" );

ContactItem contact = (ContactItem)Folder_Contacts.Items.Find(filter);

if (contact != null)
{
    contact.FullName = "Joao da Silva";
    contact.Email1Address = "joao@silva.com.br";
    contact.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://geekswithblogs.net/timh/archive/2006/05/26/79720.aspx

I might try to above.  It looks like first you reference the *Outlook COM object*, and then create a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application` from which you should be able to edit outlook objects.